# Does Object.create create an instance of an object literal?

Tags: javascript, oop

Just for the sake of being right with terminology, in this example:

```
var Cat = {
    food: 'meat',
    eat: function(){
        console.log(this.food);
    }
};


bob = Object.create(Cat);
bob.food = 'milk';

jim = Object.create(Cat);
jim.food = 'water';

bob.eat();
jim.eat();
```

Could you say that Object.create is creating an instance of the Cat object literal?

Comment: It creates a new object with prototype provided. So bobs prototype will be Cat. which is literal. It is not instance of Cat object

Comment: Literals are syntax structures, and `Object.create` does not know about them: so No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.create` "creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties". Relevant article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

I believe 'instance' is the wrong term because you aren't implementing the object in a classical inheritance way. To create a new instance you'd be using the `new` keyword in your definition. The MDN article explains it quite well.